# add new record local is working but in server doesn't work?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually when i using Visual Studio in Local everything working nice but when i upload in server (Update, delete, ...) is ok just add new is doesn't work and give me error !!!

this is my View Page code :

```
<div>
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateDealer", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Message" }))
{
<b>Add New Dealer</b>
@Html.Label("Company Name :")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.latitude) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.latitude)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.longitude)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.longitude)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.areacode)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.areacode)
@Html.Label("Address :")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address)
@Html.Label("Email :")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D_email) 
@Html.Label("Password")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D_password)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.contact)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.contact) 
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.registercode) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.registercode)
@Html.Label("promotions")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.promoid)
<p><input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" /></p>
</div>
```

My controller Code :

```
    public ActionResult CreateDealer(Dealer Mydealer)
    {
        DealerRepository Dealers = new DealerRepository();
        if (Dealers.Add(Mydealer))
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Dealer Updated";
            return PartialView("_Success", ViewBag.message);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Can't add new Dealer ... Try agan !";
            return PartialView("_UnSuccess", ViewBag.message);
        }
    }
```

and this is my class Repository:

```
public class DealerRepository
{

    private TyreShop.Models.DomainModels.Connection_db db = null;

    public DealerRepository()
    {
        db = new TyreShop.Models.DomainModels.Connection_db();
    }

    public bool Add(TyreShop.Models.DomainModels.Dealer entity, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Dealers.Add(entity);
            if (autoSave)
                return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `give me error!!!` What error??

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: return false from my class and so going to else :(

Comment: catch the exception and see what error you are getting

Comment: Pleas help meeeeee :(((((